# How to enable flexbox in bootstrap 4 rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I started a rails project and added [bootstrap gem](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem) to the Gemfile. Now I want to enable flexbox which according to the bootstrap 4 [documentation](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/flexbox/) is done by editing **_variable.scss** `$enable-flex: true`.

I added `$enable-flex: true` in `global.scss` and added this file to my `application.scss`. But it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Add `$enable-flex: true;` in `application.scss` **before** the line with `@import "bootstrap";`

it works:

`application.scss`

```
$enable-flex: true;
// Custom bootstrap variables must be set or imported before bootstrap itself.
@import "bootstrap";
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem/issues/11) issue.

It mentions the fix to be a simple variable setup in the `_bootstrap-flex.scss`
file

```
$enable-flex: true;

@import "bootstrap";
```